# Hosting a django-rest api on hostinger

Tags: django, vps

I have a project which uses django as a backend, I wish to deploy it on hostinger, anyone has already done this before? I searched alot and didn't find much help, if someone already knows, please write me the steps to successfully deploy the django backend app to hostinger

I searched alot and didn't find someone who did this before

Comment: You can use hostinger VPS panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hostinger's VPS Plan.

After purchasing the **VPS plan** they will provide you the IP address of their VPS server then **log in** to the server using **SSH**.

After login to the VPS server, you can deploy your Django Application with Apache or any other web application.

For making these changes you will need **a user with sudo permissions**.
Make a file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory as `domain.conf`.

Below is an example of Apache file **(domain.conf)** configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com
   

        ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
                ServerName domain.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html
                Alias /static /home/user_name/path_to_project_static_file
                        <Directory /home/user_name/path_to_project_static_file>
                                Require all granted
                        </Directory>


                Alias /media /home/user_name/path_to_project_media_file
                        <Directory /home/user_name/path_to_project_media_file>
                               Require all granted
                        </Directory>

                <Directory /home/user_name/project_path/project_name/wsgi.py>
                        <Files wsgi.py>
                                Require all granted
                        </Files>
                        </Directory>


                WSGIDaemonProcess process_group_name python-home=path_to_environment python-path=project_path
                WSGIProcessGroup process_group_name
                WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user_name/project_path/project_name/wsgi.py


            

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain_error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Consider making appropriate changes.

After making these changes restart your Apache service by `sudo service apache2 restart`.